# How to solve a diff. eq. when given $y=t^r$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Question follows: "Find all values of $r$ such that $y=t^r$ that satisfies the differential equation for $t>0:$ $(t^2)y″−13ty′+48y=0$

I have tried setting up with Euler's method but since r is unknown I cannot come to an answer :/ Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You just have to insert $y'=rt^{r-1}$ and $y''=r(r-1)t^{r-2}$ to get
$$
r(r-1)-13r+48=0
$$
as characteristic equation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but as I answered the response above, I am still a bit confused of how we factorise t^r

Comment: You are aware that you multiply the derivatives with compensating powers of $t$?

Comment: Ah I see now! It just got me confused when seeing a variable with a power of r-1, r-2. But it makes sense when inserting and trying, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

r can assume both 6 and 8;
assuming $y = t^r$ we get $y' = rt^{r-1}$ and $y'' = r(r-1)t^{r-2}$ filling this into the equation gives $t^r(r(r-1) -13r +48) = 0$ and as $t^r$ can't be zero it must be $(r(r-1) -13r +48)$ which should be zero with roots r=6 and r=8.

Comment: Thanks, it is the right answer!! But I do not understand how we can break out t^r when the derivatives have t^r-1 or t^r-2, we are not using the same variable anymore??

Comment: sorry for the superlate answer but there's a t and a t^2 in the equation so you only end up with t^r 's